# How to pass structure with template variable as an argument inside member function of class in c++?

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to pass 'structure with template variable' as an argument inside member function of class. I am getting error "no matching function for call to". Can anyone help me? I am doing some mistake either in declaration / definition / while passing argument from the main.

```
template <typename T>
struct msg_1{
   int var_1;
   int var_2;
   T *var_3;
};

template<typename T>
struct msg_2{
    int var_1;
    int var_2;
    T *var_3;
};

class A
{
 public:
  int a;
  int b;

  template <typename T>
  void test(T *, T *);
 };

 template <typename T>
 void A::test(T *t1, T *t2)
 {      cout<<"Inside test @todo Do something"; }

int main()
{
 A ob;
 ob.a=10;
 ob.b=20;

 msg_1<int> *ob_1 = new msg_1<int>;
 msg_2<int> *ob_2 = new msg_2<int>;

 ob.test(ob_1,ob_2);

 return 0;
}
```

========
I have accepted the given suggestion and modified the code, but getting some error while implementing. Kindly have a look.

I have passed the structure as a parameter in test method like below

```
template <typename T>
struct msg1{
…
};

template<typename U>
struct msg2{
…
};

struct msg3
{
uint16_t var_4;
};

class A
{
 public:
 int a;
 int b;

 template <typename T, typename U>
 void test(msg1<T> *t1, msg2<U> *t2);
};

template <typename T, typename U>
void A::test(msg1<T> *t1, msg2<U> *t2)
{
 cout<<"Inside test @todo Do something";
}

int main()
{
 A ob;
 ob.a=10;
 ob.b=20;

 msg_1<msg3> *ob_1 = new msg_1<msg3>;
 msg_2<msg3> *ob_2 = new msg_2<msg3>;

 ob.test(ob_1,ob_2);

 return 0;
 }
```

When I am running above code in online compiler then it’s      running fine but when I am implementing it in actual  code to do testing then I am getting compile time error
“undefined reference to ‘void A::test< msg3, msg3 > ( msg1 *, msg2 * )’.
Can anyone please tell me what possibly I am doing wrong.

Comment: `msg1<int>` and `msg2<int>` are different types, and every instantiation of `A::test` takes two pointers to the same type.

Comment: Hi molbdnilo, here I  took same types for msg1<int> and msg2<int> and took only one template with T. If possible can you share what exactly I have to do with the sample code.

Comment: Which part of "pointers to the same type" is unclear to you? `msg_1<int>` and `msg_2<int>` are not the same type. They might look the same to you, but they're not. They have different names.

Comment: It's very unclear what you're wondering. You have the same situation as `template<typename T> void f(T x, T y) {} int main() { f(12, 3.4); }`, which doesn't work because `int` and `double` are different types. If you want to pass arguments of different types, you need two template parameters.

Comment: what do you want to do actually? There are ways to fix the code but it is not clear what should stay and what should be fixed. Part of the code says `A::test` has arguments of same type, other parts wants them to be different types

Comment: maybe some of your confusion stems from all template argument sharing the same name. As molbnilo said, `msg1<int>` and `msg2<int>` are two unrelated types. The fact that they are instantiations of templates and both use `int` is irrelevant. They are different just as `struct foo { int x; }` and `struct bar {int x;};` are not the same

Comment: Thank you all of you guys for informing me that both msg1<int> and msg2<int> are different. If both are different then let me try to pass these accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template function `A::test` is only templated with one type `T` and requires that both parameters have the same type `T*`.  In your example you pass different parameters: `msg_1<int> *` and `msg_2<int> *`.

If you really want `test` to only accept two parameters with identical type, then you can't pass `ob_1` and `ob_2`. If you want `test` to accept two parameters of different type, then you can change your class `A` and function `A::test` as follows.

```
class A
{
public:
  int a;
  int b;

  template <typename T1, typename T2>
  void test(T1 *, T2 *);
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
void A::test(T1 *t1, T2 *t2)
{ cout<<"Inside test @todo Do something"; }
```

Comment: Hi Werner, Thank you for sharing the detail solution. your suggestion is correct, now it's working.